# PyTorch input shape for text classification using LSTM

Tags: nlp, lstm, pytorch, text-classification

I have three sentiment classes: POSITIVE, NEGATIVE, and NEUTRAL, along with a dataset consisting of 3000 sentences and their corresponding sentiment labels (POSITIVE, NEGATIVE, or NEUTRAL). Each sentence is represented as a $100$-dimensional vector. As a newcomer to LSTMs, I am seeking advice on the preferable approach for developing an LSTM model in PyTorch. Both approaches have a batch size of 64, with `batch_first = True.`

Approach - 1:
The input tensor should be of shape $(64,100,1)$ where each batch contains 64 sentences and each of the sentences consists of 100 timesteps where each timestep is a $1$-d vector. Basically each dimension of the sentence - vector is a timestep.

Approach - 2:
The input tensor should be of shape $(64,1,100)$ where each batch contains 64 sentences and each of the sentences consists of 1 timestep which has $100$ dimensions.

It's worth mentioning that the sentence vectors were generated by averaging the word embeddings of the tokens of each sentence. Although Approach - 1 seems more intuitive, I am unsure if the choice between the two approaches is influenced by experimental results.

Comment: Hi @PatelisGM, welcome to the site. If you are not going to feed the sequences themselves to the network, why are you using an LSTM instead of a simple linear layer or a MLP?